# Solution of 2x2 linear equation using Cramer's rule

Tags: math

I am writing a small code to solve to solve two simultaneous linear equations:
ax + by = c
dx + ey = f
where the unknowns are x, y.
I use the Cramer's rule and in the case of:
0x + 0y = 1
0x + 0y = 2
There must be no solution but the answer is indefinite number of solution since D = Dx = Dy = 0.

What is wrong here?

Comment: This is example of **inconsistent system**

Comment: If you compute AD-BC = 0, then there is no solution.  This is trivial, since 0*0-0*0 = 0.  Should be easy for your implementation to detect this.  I'd recommend checking against a small epsilon 1e-16 instead of zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is example of **inconsistent system**

Excerpt from [Mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CramersRule.html):

[image]

If `d=0`, then nondegenerate solutions exist only if `D=0`. If `d!=0` and `D=0`, **the system has no unique solution**. Otherwise, compute

```
  xk= Dk/D
```